# Подключение прокси в Python

Tags: python, proxy

Я использую вот такой код для получения ip адреса.

```
import requests

proxies = {
    "http": "http://136.243.47.220:3128"
}

r = requests.get("https://ramziv.com/ip", proxies=proxies).text
print(r)
```

Но мне всё равно возвращается мой ip адрес, а не ip адрес прокси сервера.
Как узнать подключилась ли прокси?

Comment: Немного старая тема но все же У меня не получилось Можно объяснить что где куда

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests

proxies = {
    "http": "136.243.47.220:3128", # "протокол(http/https/sock4/sock5)" : "сервер:порт"
    "https: "136.243.47.220:3128" # если протокол поддерживает http и https 
}

r = requests.get("https://ramziv.com/ip", proxies=proxies).text 
print(r)
```

Протоколы не совпадают http и https => нужно искать прокси которые поддерживают http/https